# throw an exception "duplicate entry" java.util.zip.ZipException

Tags: java, collections, collision-detection

I have a program which downloads a bunch of documents from a remote server and after, bundles them up in a .zip file using ZipOutputStream.

The problem is that when I download the files, there could be more than one file with the same file name. So, when I try to put an entry with the same file name which is in already ZipOutputStream, it will throw an exception "duplicate entry".

Is there a way, I can check for duplicate entry, before adding the zip entry to ZipOutputStream? so I can rename the duplicate file?

Please advise...

Comment: Is it your assumption that when you download two  files with same name, will remain as same name in your system ? I mean - If you download `A.java` and again `A.java`, the latter one would be renamed as `A1.java` automatically !! If some how you have file names as same, use Collections to compare names and add

Comment: yes thats want i want could u provide how provide rename mechanism in zip format

Comment: Don't know why the -1. This is an elaborated question.

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve that by adding each filename you add to an efficient data structure such as a `HashSet` and check if the name is already there. The [`add`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#add%28E%29) method, which returns `true` if the element was not already in the `Set`, and `false` otherwise.

```
Set<String> addedNames = new HashSet<String>();
// Start processing of the file set
for (String fileName : fileNames) { 
     if (addedNames.add(fileName) { 
          // Process file
     }
     else { 
         throw new DuplicateException(fileName);
     } 
}
```

Comment: filenames is not arraytype in my class its only string type

Answer (score 1):

Why not registering all of  your filenames in a sorted array/map/hash, and check all of them before adding your new file ?